# How to groupby without reset_index() based on multtindex?

Tags: pandas

**data struncture**

```
               col1  col2
A  2021-01-01
A  2022-01-01
B  2021-01-01
B  2022-01-01
```

This is a dataframe with multiindex(`ts_code`, `date`).

**Goal**

I want to get min date for `ts_code`. So I have to run `df.reset_index().groupby('ts_code')['date'].min()`. Is it any method not to reset index to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can either rename your axis for your code to work, or you can pass `level=0` into `groupby()`

Option 1:

```
df.rename_axis(['ts_code','date']).groupby('ts code')
```

Option 2:

```
df.groupby(level=0)
```

Comment: df.groupby(level=0) could not get min date for each group.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to `sort_index`; then use `groupby` + `head`:

```
df.sort_index().groupby(level=0).head(1).index
```

Or you could apply a lambda that returns the min of second index level:

```
df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.index.get_level_values(1).min())
```

Or convert the index to a DataFrame, then use `groupby` + `min`:

```
df.index.to_frame().groupby(level=0)['date'].min()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html)

```py
df.groupby(df.index.get_level_values('ts_code'))
```